# Passing env variables at runtime without quotes

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

When passing environment during docker runtime, my environment variables are getting wrapped with quotes. How am I able to set an environment variable without having it quoted?

I set the environment like such; `docker run server -e NODE_ENV=dev`

Output from the command above:

> node dist/server.js "NODE_ENV=dev"

Heres a snippet from my *Dockerfile*

```
FROM base AS release
# copy production node_modules
COPY --from=dependencies /root/app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
# copy app sources
COPY . .
# expose port and define CMD
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Comment: Have you tried `--env-file` option of `docker run`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: You're passing a command into the container here... Environment variables go before the image name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I think the sequence of your `docker run` command has a problem.

`-e` option should be before your docker image name, like this

```
docker run -e NODE_ENV=dev server
```

If its still not helping, then try [--env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) option of `docker run`.

```
docker run --env-file /path/to/server.env server
```

In `server.env`

```
NODE_ENV=dev
```

Comment: Gah, thanks man. It's always the little things. Both commands worked for me.